# Bash extended glob pattern negation is not working in parameter substitution

Tags: regex, bash, glob, parameter-expansion, extglob

Bash 3.2.57 (on macOS 12.6.8) extended glob pattern negation is not working in parameter substitution:

```bash
$ shopt -s extglob
$ s=abc
$ echo ${s##!(a)*}
```

I expected the last command to output `abc`, but it didn't output anything.

How can I make the third line output nothing if the first character of `$s` is not `'a'`, but output `$s` if the first character is `'a'`?

Comment: FYI the same thing happens in 5.1.4 on Linux.

Comment: If you only need to match the first character, you can use `${s##[^a]*}`

Comment: This should work : `echo ${s##!(a*)}`

Comment: `!(a)` matches `abc` : `[[ abc = !(a) ]] && echo matches`

Answer (score 2):

See

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ [[ abc == a!(b)c ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
$ [[ ac == a!(b)c ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

And from `man bash`:

> - `!(pattern-list)`
>
>   Matches **anything** except one of the given patterns

So here the **anything** can be a null string. <sup>(I think Bash's manual could be more explicit about this.)</sup>

Comment: If it can match the null string, that makes it fairly useless.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the third line output nothing if the first character of $s is not 'a', but output $s if the first character is 'a'?

```
case $s in a*) echo $s;; esac  # conditional execution
```

or

```
[[ $s =~ ^a ]] && echo $s      # conditional execution
```

or

```
[[ ${s:0:1} == a ]] && echo $s # conditional execution
```

or, more like what you tried,

```
echo ${s/#[^a]*/}              # string parsed to scrub nonmatch
```

Extended globbing not needed.